# Properly print html pages to pdf

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I have a html page that contains a bootstrap container and responsive images. When it rendered in browser, I want the user have the option to print the page and get a well rendered PDF. However, some images are being splatted in page transitions.

[image: Example]

Images are in thumbnail classes.

```html
{% forloop ----- %}
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="ImageShot" src="{{i.HQ_image.url}}">
              </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.ImageShot { page-break-inside: avoid; }`

You could apply this to all `img` tags as well.

Comment: I search a lot online. I've tried many things and your solution, none is working when pressing "Control + P" in Google Chrome!